# Given a list of integers, determine if 70% of the values are within 20% of one of the values

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, list, array-algorithms

I want to check if the list values have some level of "closeness". Is there a good algorithm to do this? Bonus points for the most pythonic way.

Valid

```
[1,7,8,9]
[3,4,100,101,102,103,104,105]
```

Not Valid

```
[1,8,9]
[1,10]
[100,200,300,400,500]
```

Comment: There is a good algorithm. It's called variance

Comment: @aix Nothing in the question asks about the validity of the approach. I'm pretty sure there's enough information here to come up with a valid implementation. The title gives a very specific definition to what is valid and what is not.

Comment: It is almost trivial to implement this closeness check. The question is whether this is a good notion of closeness.

Comment: Variance is only useful for normal distributions

Comment: Fairly small, usually 10-20 items. Occasionally around 100.

Comment: @MariaZverina this is actually not true. For instance, a 6 sided die has even distribution - not normal distribution. But variance can still be applied to sets of repeated rolls

Comment: @ControlAltDel Repeated dice rolls have binomial distribution which start to quickly approximated normal distribution. :-)

Comment: @MariaZverina that's my point

Comment: @ControlAltDel - variance can only be usefully applied to approximately normal distribution. And unless you make tests or determine some other way that distribution is normal, you should not make assumption of normality. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For small lists this O(n^2) algorithm will suffice:

```
def is_close(l):
    for n in l:
        c = sum([1 for x in l if x >= 0.8 *n and x <= 1.2 * n])
        if c >= 0.7 * len(l):
            return True
    return False

print is_close([1,7,8,9])
print is_close([3,4,100,101,102,103,104,105])
print is_close([1,8,9])
print is_close([1,10])
print is_close([100,200,300,400,500])
```

Output is:

```
True
True
False
False
False
```

Comment: Your tests are probably too strict. Should be `>=`, `<=`

Comment: Argh :) .. fixed too :) Brain melt ... to hot today :)

Answer (score 7):

Look up variance: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance

Comment: If using numpy, then you can compute the variance with a built in function, numpy.var(array) .

Comment: I don't see how that would work. Consider `[1, 999997, 999998, 999999, 1000000, 1000001, 1000002, 1000003, 100000000000000000, 100000000000000000000000000000 ]`. We have 70% of the values within 20% of some value, but the variance is pretty large.

Answer (score 1):

**Here is a simple linear-time algorithm** for an array `a` that is already sorted (as in the examples, otherwise it needs to be sorted beforehand in `O(n log n)` time). The idea is to construct and test each maximal subsequence that starts at a given position `low`.

```
low = middle = high = 1
while (low <= length (a))
   advance middle to the largest i such that a[i]*0.8<=a[low]
   advance high to the largest i such that a[i]<=a[middle]*1.2
   if ((high-low+1)/length(a)>=0.7) output(true)
   low = low + 1
return (false);
```

Since `low`, `middle`, and `high` are always increased from `1` through `length(a)`, the running time is always linear in `length(a)`.

If the matching subsequence of `a` is desired, one can output `a[low]...a[high]` instead of `true`.

Comment: Basically a good solution, just a few points: You don't need to go all the way until the lower end reaches the end of the array, it's sufficient that `high` reaches `length(a)` or `low` reaches `0.3 * length(a)`. Also, I wouldn't just increment `low` by 1, I'd increment `middle` by 1, then `low` until `a[low] >= 0.8*a[middle]`, then again `middle` to the largest `i` with `a[i]*0.8 <= a[low]`, then `high`. Not much difference, but it will do less work if there are big steps in the middle of the array. Anyway, the best solution here, +1.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an algorithm that takes `n logn` time.

```
sort the array
for i in range(len(array))
    begin = binary search an index such that array[begin] >= array[i]*0.2
    end = binary search an index such that array[end]*0.2 <= array[i]
    if (end - begin) <= len(array) * 0.7
        70% of the values are within %20 of array[i]
        i.e all elements between begin and end are within 20% of array[i]
```

Several optimizations, including changing the iteration order, are possible.